# Flutter multi threading save file to local

Tags: flutter, dart

```
for(var item in list)
{
    var body = (await api.get(item.url)).bodyBytes;
        await file.writeAsBytes(body);
}
```

How can I change this code to multi threading. This code is very slow. Any examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's slow because you're *forcing* your application to wait for **every** api request and **every** file write before starting the next iteration.

Start every request at the same time and wait for them all simultaneously. Multithreading will not speed up tasks that are just slow and it would not be practical in Dart.

```dart
await Future.wait(list.map((item) async {
  var body = (await api.get(item.url)).bodyBytes;
  await file.writeAsBytes(body);
}));
```

Or with a more verbose, but maybe clearer syntax:

```dart
List<Future> futures = [];
for(var item in list) {
  futures.add(Future(() async {
    var body = (await api.get(item.url)).bodyBytes;
    await file.writeAsBytes(body);
  }));
}
Future.wait(futures);
```

---

I'm not really sure why you're doing `await file.writeAsBytes(body);` with the same file every iteration, but it appears to be a mistake to me. Just be aware.

Comment: Exception has occurred.
SocketException (SocketException: Connection failed (OS Error: Too many open files, errno = 24), I have change code to list<future> futures=[]....

Comment: @Miles So my answer worked? If my answer helped, please click the checkmark to accept it. If this was not satisfactory, please clarify why you're using the same `file` object to write different data.